# SQL: efficiently get the last record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have a table order which contains order date.

```
WarehouseId | OrderId | ItemId | OrderDate
-------------------------------------------
          1 |       1 |      1 | 2016-08-01
          1 |       2 |      2 | 2016-08-02
          1 |       3 |      5 | 2016-08-10
          2 |       1 |      1 | 2016-08-05
          3 |       1 |      6 | 2016-08-06
```

(table is simplified and only shown required fields)

How to efficiently select the last order for particular Warehouse? I am currently do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblOrder WHERE WarehouseId = 1 ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

My concern is, when I have a million (or more) orders for particular warehouse, by doing sorting and select the first record, it will be too slow (I think?).

Is there any more efficient way to select the last order record?

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie? (I.e. two rows with same last date.)

Comment: Your approach is not very expensive and should work fine in the case then there is an index (WarehouseID, OrderDate) on your table.

Comment: if you're going to it a lot, you could consider setting an index on the orderdate field, that will speed things up (but be aware it might have an impact on other queries against this table - it's a complicated topic, talk to a DBA!). Otherwise, your query is fine, unless you're worried about identical dates like the above commenter said

Comment: what is the table schema..?

Comment: @jarlh, you are right. I should probably do ORDER BY OrderId instead. Can you see any downside of doing OrderBy OrderId?

Comment: @Andy and ADyson, I will change the order using "OrderId". OrderId is composite primary key of WarehouseId and OrderId

Comment: @ADyson & Andy, please post your answer (that it is not an expensive operation), then I will accept it as answer.

Comment: This question might be better suited on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to it a lot, you could consider setting an index on the `OrderDate` field. That will speed things up (but be aware it might have an impact on other queries against this table - it's a complicated topic, talk to a DBA!).

Otherwise, your query is fine, unless you're worried about the ordering when there are identical dates, in which case you should decide on a secondary field to order by as well, such as OrderID (which you suggested in the comments).

Comment: I'm using OrderId (which is a composite primary key). I guess it should be fine?

Comment: I'd have thought so yes